# Finder: go to parent folder while dragging files

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

Is there a short(-cut) way to move to the parent file while you drag files? So you can e.g. move them to the parent folder outside of the current folder.

Unfortunately CMD + Arrow Up doesn't work while dragging.

Otherwise what would be the best technique?

[image: dragging a file]

Comment: Have you tried command-left bracket? Of course that is the previous folder so as long as the previous folder is the parent folder it should go there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default short-cut to move an item one level up in the folder hierarchy.

But you can enable "Show Path Bar" with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, drag the item to the respective superior folder in the path bar and double-click the destination folder.

---

Alternatively you can create a service with Automator and an embedded AppleScript and finally assign a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have the option to use the copy & paste method. Select the file and press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it. Open or go to the Folder that you want to move the file. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to move the file to the destination folder.
2. Method as described by @klanomath with the "Show Path Bar". You can Drag and Drop the file directly to one of the destination folders shown in the Path Bar.

Comment: I've been using Mac for 7 years and TIL option+command+v is move, thanks!